# Why does undo select all channels in graph editor?

Tags: interface, graph-editor, fcurves

I select any channel (with only show selected option or\and with show only selected curve keyframes option on) then modify keyframes on f-curve, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for undo and all channels become selected again.

Which settings have influence on that? All versions of blender on my PC have same behavior.

Here is a gif of the problem.
[image: gif]

Comment: Looks like it's undoing till the moment when you deselected all the other FCurves and selected only one to edit. *"All versions of blender on my PC have same behavior"* which versions are these? Do you use the latest one?

Comment: these are 2.76-2.79. It happens with bones in pose mode. When you insert a couple of keyframes on any control of rigged character then go to graph editor you see that all channels and keyframes are already selected there so you are maybe right about undoing it to the start.. But in object mode if i keyframe cube for example, channels in grapheditor are deselected and after undo channels stay deselected... So it happens with bones only